# A small doubt related to Hatcher Example 2.31.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a small doubt related to the example 2.31. of Hatcher Algebraic Topology. I am wariting the passage below.

Let $k\in \Bbb N$ and $q:S^n\to {\large\lor}_kS^n$ be the quotient map obtained by collapsing the complement of $k$ disjoint open balls $B_i$ in $S^n$ to a point. Also let $p:{\large\lor}_kS^n\to S^n$ identify all the summands to a single sphere. Consider $f=pq$. Now for **almost all** $y\in S^n$ we have $f^{-1}(y)$ consisting of one point $x_i$ in each $B_i$.

My question is the words **almost all** can be replaced by the words **all but one**. I mean we can write, for **all but one point** (here one refers to the wedge point) $y\in S^n$ we have $f^{-1}(y)$ consisting of one point $x_i$ in each $B_i$. Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can be more precise. The proposition that is applied later only needs one $y$ with finitely many pre-images, so even less precision than *almost all* suffices.

Comment: "almost all" (in topological context for sure) means all but finitely many. All but one is just a minor precision, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, you are right.

Comment: Isn't it the case, though, that ALL $y \in S^n$ are have one pre-image due to the fact that we took open balls $B_i$ that don't include the wedge point? (i.e., I'm claiming that the wedge point does not map back to $B_i$ since we collapsed the complements of these to a point).

Comment: @Anon The preimage of the wedge point is the complement of the union of the open balls. All other points of $S^n$ have $k$ points in their preimage, one in each open ball.